# planar representation of $K_n$

Tags: graph-theory

Give a planar representation of $K_n$ that has $\binom{n }{4}$ crossings.
What is the meaning of $\binom{n }{4}$ crossings in this planar representation ?

Try on : I figure out of $K_n$, for example $K_8$, it has 18 crossings.

[image]

Can someone help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Given any four points.  Draw straight lines between each pair.  There are six lines, and one crossing.
So drawing straight lines between $n$ points will give $n\choose4$ crossings, although some may coincide.
Try to arrange the points so none of the crossings coincide.

Comment: how about the figure of $K_8$ that i attach, is it true ?

Comment: Several sets of four points have no crossings, which reduced the number of crossings from ${8\choose4}=70$ to your 18.

Answer (score 3):

If you draw $n$ points on a circle and join all of them by lines s.t there is no point that it's intersection of $3$ lines or more, then you have $\binom{n }{4}$ cross points. Because each crossing corresponds to $4$ points.
This picture describes what I said for $n=6$ [image]